# Database sql query to get the values based on the minimum date of end of month data

Tags: sql, database

For example if I have a car data and want to get the minimum of repair date when a specific car id has changed its particular insurance?

I tried grouping on car_id and Insurance but unsure how to get the min(repair_date) in this case. [image]

Comment: please provide your query, what have You already tried?

Comment: please add your table structure on your question

Comment: Read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This seems straightforward:

```
select car_id, insurance, min(repair_date)
from repairs
group by car_id, insurance
```

Comment: I think you are right. Unfortunately, it was just bad data as I had no such record which was leading to this confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this

select * from 
(select car_id, insurance, repair_date
from repairs
order by car_id, insurance, repair_date ASC) as a
group by car_id, insurance;

That select within the () orders your rows so that the most recent date comes first, and thus is the one presented when you group.